# Aligning data vertically in td elements for horizontally connected rows using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I've html in the below format.

```
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
         var dups = $('.comps + .comps');
         dups.remove();
     });     
     var list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
     var list2 = [6,5,4,3,2,1];
</script>

<div class="serverSet">
  <h2>JH Storefront servers</h2>
  <table border="1" class="CSSTableGenerator" class="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Component</th>
      <th>Properties</th>
      <th class="servers"> lqwasc10 </th>
      <th class="servers"> lqwasc11 </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="comps">DeliveryMethodsRepository</td>
      <td class="props">externalCacheBatchInfoSize</td>
    <tr/>
    <tr/>
      <td class="comps">InventoryManager</td>
      <td class="comps">InventoryManager</td>
      <td class="props">itemType</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="comps">InventoryManager</td>
      <td class="props">maxConcurrentUpdateRetries</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="comps">CatalogTools</td>
      <td class="comps">CatalogTools</td>
      <td class="props">queryASAFFabrics</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="comps">CatalogTools</td>
      <td class="props">loggingDebug</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="comps">CatalogTools</td>
      <td class="props">outOfStockCode</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

In the above jquery function, `list1` and `list2` are horizontally connected to `lqwasc10` and `lqwasc11` respectively. Is there a way I can align list1 and list2 vertically along with existing `td` elements of `Components` and `Properties` in their respective orders.

I've tried a lot and couldn't get hold of the logic. It would be great if someone can answer.

I'm expecting data in the format as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Expected tabular data]

Comment: Why do you do `var dups = $('.comps + .comps');
         dups.remove();` this and dont just remove the duplicates? Furthermore you have 2 errors in your html code. The 2 lines right below the `externalCacheBatchInfoSize` should be `</tr><tr>` instead of `<tr/><tr/>`.

Comment: There is also an opening `tr` tag at the end of the table which is not closed...

Comment: Hi, the jquery I used is for removing duplicates. It is for a different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can merely add the desired `<td>`s just after removing duplicates, like this:

```js
var list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var list2 = [6,5,4,3,2,1];
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.comps + .comps').remove();
  $('.myTable tr').each(function(i) {
    if (i > 0) {
      $(this)
        .append('<td>' + list1[i - 1] + '</td>')
        .append('<td>' + list2[i - 1] + '</td>');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="serverSet">
  <h2>JH Storefront servers</h2>
  <table border="1" class="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Component</th>
      <th>Properties</th>
      <th class="servers"> lqwasc10 </th>
      <th class="servers"> lqwasc11 </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="comps">DeliveryMethodsRepository</td>
      <td class="props">externalCacheBatchInfoSize</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="comps">InventoryManager</td>
      <td class="comps">InventoryManager</td>
      <td class="props">itemType</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="comps">InventoryManager</td>
      <td class="props">maxConcurrentUpdateRetries</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="comps">CatalogTools</td>
      <td class="comps">CatalogTools</td>
      <td class="props">queryASAFFabrics</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="comps">CatalogTools</td>
      <td class="props">loggingDebug</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="comps">CatalogTools</td>
      <td class="props">outOfStockCode</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Please note that this snippet works only after correcting HTML errors: `<tr>` inconsistency (already noticed by comments), duplicate `class` attribute on `<table>`.